# Make progressbar with multiple circles

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-progressbar

Before the question was flagged as being asked before. I've searched for days and still cant find something that looks like this. I'm able to make a single circle progress bar and change the color but I cant seem to make one with multiple circles like seen below.

[image]

Been searching for a way to make multiple lines like that with xml but couldn't find any.

Comment: in xml? no, you have to use a custom `View` to make such things

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a third party library. You can directly use it or just study the code of it. You will get some idea by that. https://github.com/generic-leo/SimpleArcLoader

If the ans solved your problem Mark this as accepted.

Comment: Wow thanks. That's the closest to what I'm trying to do. I'll use it and see if it can give me the same type of design. If it works I'll definitely come back and mark it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay sir, I will surely appreciate it.